# accessing contacts in ios

Tags: cloud, contacts, icloud, import-contacts

I am developing an app that aggregates various data sources.  Is it possible to access IOS contacts/calendar/reminders and aggregate & upload this data from the app or would this violate the app store regulations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if the user allows you to do that and you will give him mechanisms for removing those data you uploaded it can work out.

Why did you mark this question as iCloud?